# Approximate point spectrum is complement of set of points of regular type

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question concerning the approximate point spectrum of a closed linear operator. I need to show that the approximate point spectrum is the complement of the set of points of regular type, where

$\sigma_{ap}(T)=\{\lambda \in \mathbb C: \exists (x_n) \subset D(T), \|x_n\|=1, (T−\lambda)x_n \to 0,n \to \infty \}$ and $\Lambda(T)= \{ \lambda \in \mathbb C: \exists C>0 \|(T- \lambda)x\| \geq C \|x\|, x \in D(T) \}$.

I.e. I need to prove that $\sigma_{ap}(T)= \mathbb C \setminus \Lambda(T)$.

I know that one can show it with the closed graph Theorem but I don't know exactly how. Can please someone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you prove one containment?

Comment: My idea is the following:

Comment: My idea is the following: 
Let $\lambda \in \sigma_{ap}(T)$, then, by Definition $\exists (x_n) \subset D(T), \|x_n\|=1, (T- \lambda)x_n \to 0, n \to \infty$ this means that $(\|(T-\lambda)x_n\|)$ is a null sequence. This gives for every $C>0$ and $(x_n)$ as above an $x_{n(C)} \in D(T)$ such that $\forall n > n(C)$ we have $\|(T-\lambda)x_n\| < C \|x_n\|$. This implies that $\Lambda \notin \Gamma(T)$.

Is this correct? Does the other direction work like this too?

Answer (score 0):

The prrof of $\def\sap{\sigma_{\rm ap}}\sap(T) \subseteq \def\CL{\mathbf C \setminus \Lambda}\CL(T)$ you gave in your comment is correct.

For the other inclusion, suppose $\lambda \in \CL(T)$. Then 
$$ \forall C > 0 \;\exists x \in D(T): \def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}\norm{(T-\lambda)x} < C\|x\| $$
Now for every $n \in \def\N{\mathbf N}\N$ choose $x_n' \in D(T)$ such that 
$$ \norm{(T-\lambda)x_n'} < \frac 1n \norm{x_n'}$$
Now let $x_n := \frac{x_n'}{\norm{x_n'}}$. Then $\norm{x_n} = 1$ and 
$$ \norm{(T- \lambda)x_n} < \frac 1n \to 0 $$
Hence $\lambda \in \sap(T)$.